# Prove that $f(z)=z^4$ is a group homomorphism

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism

If $f:(\mathbb C^*,.) \to (\mathbb C^*,.)$ is defined by

$f(z)=z^4$

1- Prove that $f$ is a group homomorphism.

2- find $\mathrm{ker}(f)$.

1- $f(z.y)=(zy)^4=z^4.y^4$

$f(z)=z^4$, $f(y)=y^4$

$f(z).f(y)=z^4.y^4$

So $f(z.y)=f(z).f(y)$

Then $f$ is a group homomorphism.

True ?

And what about $\mathrm{ker}(f)$ ?

Comment: Which complex numbers satisfy $z^4=1$?

Comment: There are three other roots of $z^4-1$: $-i$, and $\pm 1$.

Comment: You have shown the morphism respects operations. You also have to show that it sends the identity to the identity, but this is obvious. The kernel is the set of elements which are mapped to the identity. Once you know this, it should be easy. Hint: you will have to solve a polynomial equation.

Answer (score 0):

The first part is good, you have shown that $f$ preserves products. To calculate the kernel, $ker=\{z  | z^4=1\}$. These are $\{1,-1,i,-i\}$, check by definition.